# Get the value of div that a href is linked to with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the div id that a href is linked to when user click on, with jQuery.

How can I achieve this?

```
<a href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
<div id="2"> <a id="tips">Useful Tips Section</a></div>
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information to properly answer this. It would be better if you gave the full structure of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user2135872: Check out my answer below. I think this is what you meant. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below attaches an on-click handler to the first anchor element (i.e., the one with the `href`). It then gets the `id` of the `<div>` that is the parent of the other anchor element..

```
$('a[href]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $thisAnchor = $(this);
    var $otherAnchor = $($(this).attr('href'));
    var $div = $otherAnchor.parent();
    var divId = $div.attr('id');
});
```

Of course, you could shorten this up, but I put in the intermediate variables to show the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.

```
$("a#tips").click(function(){
    $(this).parent();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your script is similar to this:

```
    <div id="foo">
    <img id="my_img" src="/somewhere_on_my_server/one_img.jpg">
    </div>
```

you can get the div's id like this

```
    $(function() {
        $('img').click(function(e){
            alert( $(this).parent('div').attr('id'))
        })
    });
```

note in stead of parent() you can also use closest(). both go up the tree

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a[href]').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  console.log($(id).html());
});
```

**[JSBIN DEMO](http://jsbin.com/oqANOmi/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

Add class to the link to be clicked

```
<a class='someclass' href="#tips">Visit the Useful Tips Section</a>
<div id="2"> <a id="tips">Useful Tips Section</a></div>
```

**JS**

Attach event to the link so that on click of it you can get div id with this

```
$(function () {
    $('.someclass').click(function () {
        $(this).attr('href')).parent(); // gets you the div that you require
        $(this).attr('href')).parent().attr('id') // gives you div id that a is linked to
        console.log($($(this).attr('href')).parent().attr('id')); // print div id 2
    });
});
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/75yut/

Answer (score 0):

Give a try

```
$("#tips").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().attr("id");
 });
```